# How to send an SMS by using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, sms, phpmailer

I want to send an SMS by using phpMailer, I tried to do all configuration but I'm getting message

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Access denied - Invalid
>   HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) in C:\xampp\htdocs

Below are my codes

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try{                            
$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'mail.ku..e.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
$mail->Username = 'info@ku..e.com';              
$mail->Password = 'my password';                      
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
$mail->Port = 25;   
//$mail->Port = 25;

$to = "+25078.....@vtext.com";
$from = "info@k..e.com";
$message = "aaaaa";

$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Your name <info@ku..e.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
mail($to, '', $message, $headers);

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I configured php.ini like this

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.ku..e.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;username = info@ku..e.com
;password = my password
;sendmail_from = info@ku..e.com
```

I use inmotion hosting

Please anyone can help me to send an sms by using above codes

Comment: Disabled SMTP authentication in mail clients for "550 Access denied" error and check the ports

Answer (score 0):

Uh, you're not using PHPMailer! You start to, but then you give up and switch to using `mail()`! Replace this part:

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Your name <info@ku..e.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
mail($to, '', $message, $headers);
```

with:

```
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->setFrom('info@ku..e.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->send();
```

Then you will be using PHPMailer properly, and sending via SMTP in the way I assume you
intended.

As far as sending SMS goes, PHPMailer has no opinion on that - if you have a reliable email to SMS gateway, then it should work fine. That said, it's unlikely your SMS gateway wants HTML input, so you probably need to delete the `$mail->isHTML();` line to make it send as text/plain, and you probably want to use `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` as well (and ensure that your content is in UTF-8).

Comment: Hello Synchro, I tried to use your point but when I browse my file there is not any message I get. I used port=25 or 587

Comment: If you mean you get a blank page, it means there is a fatal error - check your server's error log. `tls` mode will work on port 25 or 587, but when used with authentication, 587 is more commonly used for message submission (outbound).